# List of elements in the group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

There are $8$ elements in the group $\mathbb{Z_4}\times \mathbb{Z_4^*}$.

I am having trouble listing the eight elements.  Note: $\mathbb{Z_4^*}$ means group of units in $\mathbb{Z_4}$.

Comment: Do you know the elements of each of those groups? How have you had the product of groups defined?

Comment: Can you name the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_4^*$?

Answer (score 2):

Now, $\mathbb Z_4\{0, 1, 2, 3\}$. And $\mathbb Z_4^* = \{1, 3\}.\;$

$(*)$ Exercise (if you aren't clear about the elements of $\,\mathbb Z_4^*):\;$ confirm that for all non-negative $\,k\in \mathbb Z,\, 3^k \equiv 1\pmod 4\,$ or $\,3^k \equiv 3\pmod 4.\;$ Indeed, $\;\langle 3\rangle = \mathbb Z_4^*.$

The elements of $\,\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_4^*\,$ are ordered pairs of elements of the form $\,(a, b),\,$ with  $\,a\in \mathbb Z_4,\,$ and $\,b\in \mathbb Z_4^*$.

Now all that remains is to list all eight such ordered pairs.

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb{Z_4}$$\times \mathbb{Z_4^*}$={${(0,1),(0,3),(1,1),(1,3),(2,1),(2,3),(3,1),(3,3)}$}, where obviously $\mathbb{Z_4^*}$={$1,3$}